# How can I remember to supercall the parent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, overriding

I am using Unity, where there is a few very common methods, such as `Start()` and `Update()`.  Whenever I inherit from another class, I override the parent's methods, but I always forget to call `base.ParentMethod();`.

Is there a way I prevent myself from doing this?  It causes lots of bugs that I waste a lot of time searching for.  Is there a setting in Visual Studio that will automatically call the base method when I override something?  Is there some sort of check I can do to see which methods I am forgetting to make the base calls for?

Ideally, I want to force Visual Studio to give me a warning when I forget to make the base call.  Can I do this, or something similar?

Comment: The way to do this depends on the version of Visual Studio you are using. There are features in 2015 that make this a lot easier to do. You can write a analyzer to detect if you are making a mistake. Does not solve your problem, but this one might interest you https://github.com/meng-hui/UnityEngineAnalyzer

Comment: Frankly you just need to get into the habit figuring out what the base implementation does and decide for yourself whether or not you _need_ to call it. Depending on the situation, you don't always want to call the base implementation.  Sometimes it would even be an error to attempt to call a base implementation.  There's no way for VS to know that for you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you for your feedback. i am using visual studio 2015 as a matter of fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach to this problem is to use the [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). In the base class, make the method sealed, and call another abstract or virtual method:

```
public sealed TheMethod()
{
    // Do something that should always be done
    DoSomethingImportant()

    // Call the derived class implementation
    TheMethodCore();
}

protected abstract void TheMethodCore();
```

This way, there is no way for the derived class to "forget" to call the base method; `DoSomethingImportant` will always be called.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually overriding the base method, once you have defined your class with inheritance like below; type `override` and hit `spacebar` which will bring up all method that can be overridden and once you select one of the member of baseclass it will automatically generate the method stub along with the line `base.method();` in overridden method body.

```
public class myclass : parentclass
{

}
```

**If not wrong, this trick works even in `Visual Studio 2010`

Answer (score 0):

This is done by Visual Studio if you just write override and select method from InteliSense. However, since Roslyn you can also create (or find some) analyser that would check it and supress some warning/info after the compilation (Im not sure if its available for the Unity tho).